# Can a server handle multiple sockets in a single thread?

Tags: sockets

I'm writing a test program that needs to emulate several connections between virtual machines, and it seems like the best way to do that is to use Unix domain sockets, for various reasons.  It doesn't really matter whether I use SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM, but it seems like SOCK_STREAM is easier/simpler for my usage.

My problem seems to be a little backwards from the typical scenario.  I want to have a single client communicating with the server over 4 distinct sockets.  (I could have 4 clients with one socket each, but that distinction shouldn't matter.)  Now, the thing I'm emulating doesn't have multiple threads and gets an interrupt whenever a data packet is received over one of the "sockets".  Is there some easy way to emulate this with Unix sockets?

I believe that I have to do the `socket()`, `bind()`, and `listen()` for all 4 sockets first, then do an `accept()` for all 4, and do `fcntl( fd, F_SETFF, FNDELAY )` for each one to make them nonblocking, so that I can check each one for data with `read()` in a round-robin fashion.  Is there any way to make it interrupt-driven or event-driven, so that my main loop only checks for data in the socket if there's data there?  Or is it better to poll them all like this?

Comment: You want to look at the `select` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Handling multiple connections is almost synonymous with "server", and they are often single threaded -- but please not this way:

> check each one for data with read() in a round-robin fashion

That would require, as you mention, non-blocking sockets and some kind of delay to prevent your "round-robin" from becoming a system killing busy loop.

A major problem with that is the granularity of the delay.  You can't make it too small, or the loop will still hog too much CPU time when nothing is happening.  But what about when something *is* happening, and that something is data incoming simultaneously on multiple connections? Now your delay can produce a snowballing backlog of tish leading to refused connections, etc.

It just is not feasible, and *no one* writes a server that way, although I am sure anyone would give it serious thought if they were unaware of the library functions intended to tackle the problem.  Note that networking is a platform specific issue, so these are not actually part of the C standard (which does not deal with sockets at all).

The functions are `select()`, `poll()`, and `epoll()`; the last one is linux specific and the other two are POSIX.  The basic idea is that the call blocks, waiting until one or more of *any number* of active connections is ready to read or write.  Waiting for a socket to be ready to write only meaningfully applies to NON_BLOCK sockets.  You don't have to use NON_BLOCK, however, and the `select()` call blocks regardless.  Using NON_BLOCK on the individual sockets makes the implementation more complex, but increases performance potential in a single threaded server -- this is the idea behind *asynchronous* servers (such as **nginx**), a paradigm which contrasts with the more traditional threaded synchronous model.

However, I would recommend that you not use NON_BLOCK initially because of the added complexity.  When/if it ends up being called for, you'll know.  You still do not need threads.

There are many, many, many examples and tutorials around about how to use `select()` in particular.